# FilterMap function define

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to get a program, which first filters out the elements that match the condition from the list, then maps the elements based on a function that is also received as a parameter.

```
filterMap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
```

For instance:

```
filterMap (+1) even [1..10] == [3,5,7,9,11]
filterMap (2^) (/=0) [0,1,0,2] == [2,4]
```

Comment: Great function! What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Hint: list comprehensions are your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to point out the problem itself with your attempts on this.

However, here are some versions of what you are looking for:

- simple version, use filter and map directly:

```
filterMap :: (a->b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
filterMap mapping pred lst = map mapping (filter pred lst)
```

- version without parentheses:

```
filterMap mapping pred lst = map mapping $ filter pred $ lst
```

- composition version:

```
filterMap mapping pred = map mapping . filter pred
```

Here we've got rid of an argument on both sides (so called [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)) and say that our function is a sequence of filtering with `pred` and mapping with, well, `mapping`.

Comment: Thanks it helps for me!